# Volley + OkHttp on Android gives error on status 200 response

Tags: android, android-volley, okhttp

When I make my request with only Volley everything goes well and my StringRequest goes to onResponse.

But when I switch to Volley + Okhttp combination, my request goes through, I receive the same response as before but then I get the following error message:

```
E/Volley﹕ [122319] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 200 for <my request url>
java.io.IOException: closed
    com.android.volley.NetworkError: java.io.IOException: closed
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:182)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
     Caused by: java.io.IOException: closed
            at okio.RealBufferedSource$1.read(RealBufferedSource.java:345)
            at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:162)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.entityToBytes(BasicNetwork.java:254)
            at com.android.volley.toolbox.BasicNetwork.performRequest(BasicNetwork.java:130)
            at com.android.volley.NetworkDispatcher.run(NetworkDispatcher.java:114)
```

Im using this https://gist.github.com/bryanstern/4e8f1cb5a8e14c202750 for my OkHttpStack for Volley.

Comment: do you got any solution for this. I am getting this Volley: [168] "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 200" for <my url> on Emulator only but on device its working fine. :( what could be the issue. Please give any pointer/directions. Thanks

Comment: Sorry I have moved on to Retrofit since then and haven't looked into it since then

Answer (score 2):

I haven't had too much time to investigate but I was running into the same issue when using the emulator connected through a proxy (Charles). For me the problem goes away when I test without a proxy or on device.

Comment: I am getting this Volley: [168] "BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 200" for <my url> on Emulator only but on device its working fine. And yes my system crosses a proxy server. I have tried same by removing my system from proxy tunnel still facing the same issue

Comment: @user3062722 This should be accepted answer man, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

This exact same problem happened to me when using the start and stop methods of the RequestQueue. It was pointed out in many popular blogs that the RequestQueue should be stopped when user is flinging to ensure there's no jerking. However when you call stop, all RequestQueue's requests are stopped, even the ones which were already doing network call. The above exception happened when these requests are stopped preliminarily. Not calling the stop function solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

For those people using a Proxy (in my case Charles) besides configuring your proxy in Settings it is necessary to configure also your proxy in the Android Emulator.

So, here is my configuration in Settings Emulator

[image]

And this are the steps to configure the proxy using wifi in Android Emulator

1. Settings
2. Network & Internet
3. Wi-Fi
4. Android Wifi
5. Click on Setting icon
6. Click Edit icon

[image]

7. Configure your proxy

[image]